# Can I bring a large sum of inheritance money into the U.S. through an airport?

Tags: united-states, taxes, money-transfer, inheritance, travel

I'm an international student in the United States. I inherited around 1 million USD from my father.

Can I bring that money into the U.S. through an airport?

Comment: Like in a briefcase?

Comment: And is it actual US currency, or a bank account, investments. or anything but a pile of $100 bills?

Comment: That sounds extremely suspicious. I'd have a lot of questions for you if I were there CBP agent processing you at the airport. Even in the best case, you're going to be pulled aside for extensive questioning.

Comment: That's also ignoring the obvious risks of carrying that much cash around anywhere.

Comment: Posting as a comment because I dont have a handle on all the details -  CBP info, you can carry it in but you need to declare it. https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/kbyg/money . The IRS may have a similar requirement, as an international student do you currently have to file or pay taxes in the US?

Comment: Why can't you wire the money?

Comment: @Freiheit+ if you are resident _for tax purposes_ in US -- which foreign students and scholars are NOT for several years even though physically present -- IRS cares about the inheritance no matter where you put it. IRS doesn't care about transport. If you import over $10k cash without getting it seized or stolen, and put it in a bank, the bank reports to FinCEN (not IRS); if you spend it at certain businesses like a car dealer, due to a historical quirk the dealer files 8300 with IRS but IRS just forwards it to FinCEN -- there's no tax for _having_ money. But this smells like troll to me.

Answer (score 13):

Technically, yes.  But it may not be a good idea.

You will need to declare it, because it's over $10000.  And you will have to explain to the officer why you are carrying $1M.  **If they don't believe your explanation, they will take the money from you.**

Comment: You won't only have this issue with customs. Any police officer that catches you with that much money will probably take it and claim it's drug money. Even if you can prove otherwise, good luck getting it back.

Comment: Worse yet, walking into a bank with one million dollars cash and trying to deposit into an existing bank account (or trying to open a new bank account with such a large cash deposit) will not work very well either.